# ASP.Net Core 2.1 Angular App - No errors when debugging but stuck on loading

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-core

This is my very first post in this site.

For the past days I've been trying to figure this one out but no luck.

I have an aspnet core 2.1 application with angular and it works just fine on my local machine (I know this sounds very familiar). I published it and put it in the server where IIS is installed. So far, so good.

Problem is, before hosting it with IIS I decided to debug it from the IIS server with the dotnet sdk by running nameofapp.exe on the command prompt. I get a "now listening on http://localhost:5000" which is the default host when debugging and I don't get any errors.

Now, when I make a request on http://localhost:5000 I only receive the "Loading" message from the index.html file.

I have tried so many things, none have worked; I am even thinking to start the application from scratch and publish it little by little (I know, not the best thing to do). One of the solutions I found which I really thought was going to work was changing the base href on the index.html from "/" to "" but it didn't work. I changed it to "./" and to "." but nothing.

Here are some files of the application on the angular side. Is still in its early stages though. There are only 2 components (app.component) and (nav-menu.component). The only thing the app.component does is it calls the nav-menu-component. The nav-menu component has a bunch of functions that are not really relevant, just want to show how the app is structured. I am also including the app.module.ts file and index.html.

**app.component.ts:**

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent{
      title = 'app';

      }
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<nav-menu></nav-menu>
```

**nav-menu.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints, BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { RefillService } from './refill.service';
import { RefillModel } from './refill.model';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatSort, MatSnackBar } from "@angular/material";
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';

@Component({
  selector: 'nav-menu',
  templateUrl: './nav-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-menu.component.css']
})
export class NavMenuComponent {

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  addOrdersButtonDisabled: boolean = true;
  submitOrdersButtonDisabled: boolean = true;
  dataLoadingProgress: boolean = true;
  rowsIndex: number;
  refillOrderCount: number;
  orderRefillsIndex: number;
  rows: RefillModel[] = [];
  orderRefills: RefillModel[] = [];
  title = 'app';
  refill: RefillModel;
  dataSource;
  dataSourceOrderQueue;
  emptyDatasource = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['select', 'doctorFullName', 'patientFullName', 'patientDateOfBirth', 'medicationName', 'writtenQuantity', 'refillsLeft', 'writtenDate', 'submitDate', 'lastOrderLineStatus', 'lastRefillDate', 'directions'];
  emptyDatasourceOrderQueue = [];
  displayedColumnsOrderQueue: string[] = ['delete', 'doctorFullName', 'patientFullName', 'medicationName']
  selection = new SelectionModel<RefillModel>(true, []);

  isHandset: Observable<BreakpointState> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset);
  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver, private service: RefillService, public snackbar: MatSnackBar) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.getRefills();
  }

  getRefills() {
    this.service.getRefills().subscribe(data => {
      this.refill = data.json();
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data.json());
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataLoadingProgress = false;

    });

  }

  initializeOrderQueueTable() {
    this.dataSourceOrderQueue = new MatTableDataSource(this.emptyDatasourceOrderQueue);
  }
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
      this.selection.clear() :
      this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }


  getValues(row: RefillModel, selectedRow: boolean) {


    this.rowsIndex = this.rows.indexOf(row);


    if (!selectedRow) {

      if (this.rowsIndex === -1) {
        this.rows.push(row);
        this.orderRefills.push(row);

      }

    }
    else {

      if (this.rowsIndex !== -1) {
        this.rows.splice(this.rowsIndex, 1);
        this.orderRefills.splice(this.rowsIndex, 1);
      }

    }


  }

  deleteOrder(element: any) {

    this.orderRefillsIndex = this.orderRefills.indexOf(element);
    this.orderRefills.splice(this.orderRefillsIndex, 1);
    this.rows.splice(this.orderRefillsIndex, 1);
    this.dataSourceOrderQueue = new MatTableDataSource(this.orderRefills);
    // console.log(element); 
  }

  AddSelectedRefillsToQueue() {
    this.dataSourceOrderQueue = new MatTableDataSource(this.orderRefills);
    this.selection.clear();
  }
  submitSelectedRefills() {


    this.service.submitRefills(this.orderRefills).subscribe(response => console.log(response));
    this.snackbar.open('Refill Order(s) Submitted', '', {
      duration: 3000
    });

  }
}
```

**nav-menu.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
    fixedInViewport="true"
    [attr.role]="isHandset ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="(isHandset | async)!.matches ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [opened]="!(isHandset | async)!.matches">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">Pharmacy Refills</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <!-- <a mat-list-item routerLinkActive="active" href="">Active Refills</a>  -->
      <a mat-list-item routerLinkActive="active" href="#">Inactive Refills</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLinkActive="active" href="#">Orders Submitted</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="(isHandset | async)!.matches">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>Active Refills</span>
    </mat-toolbar>

    <mat-card>  
      <mat-card-content>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
      </mat-form-field>


    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">


     <!-- Checkbox Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        Select
      </th>
      <td  mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                      (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                      [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                      (click)="getValues(row,selection.isSelected(row))"

                    >
        </mat-checkbox>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

       <ng-container matColumnDef="doctorFullName">
          <th mat-header-cell  *matHeaderCellDef> Prescriber </th>
          <td mat-cell  *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.doctorFullName}} </td>
        </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="patientFullName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Patient </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.patientFullName}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="patientDateOfBirth">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Patient DOB </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.patientDateOfBirth | date:'shortDate'}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="medicationName">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Medication </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.medicationName}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="writtenQuantity">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Quantity </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.writtenQuantity}} </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="refillsLeft">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Refills Remaining </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.refillsLeft}} </td>
            </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="writtenDate">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Start Date </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.writtenDate | date:'shortDate' }} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="submitDate">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last Order Date </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.submitDate | date:'shortDate' }} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="lastOrderLineStatus">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last Order Status </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.lastOrderLineStatus}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="lastRefillDate">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last Refill Date </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.lastRefillDate | date:'shortDate' }} </td>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container matColumnDef="directions">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Directions </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.directions }} </td>
                </ng-container>


        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
      (click)="selection.toggle(row)"></tr>


      </table>

      <div *ngIf="dataLoadingProgress">
          <mat-progress-bar mode="query">
          </mat-progress-bar>
        </div>



    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="AddSelectedRefillsToQueue()">Add Refill Orders to Queue</button>

    </mat-card>

    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header>
          <h3>Refill Order Queue</h3>
          </mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-content>
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceOrderQueue">

          <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
              <th mat-header-cell  *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
              <td mat-cell  *matCellDef="let element">
              <button
              type="button" 
              mat-icon-button
              (click)="deleteOrder(element)"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </td> 
            </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="doctorFullName">
           <th mat-header-cell  *matHeaderCellDef> Prescriber </th>
           <td mat-cell  *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.doctorFullName}} </td>
         </ng-container>

     <ng-container matColumnDef="patientFullName">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Patient </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.patientFullName}} </td>
       </ng-container>
       <ng-container matColumnDef="medicationName">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Medication </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.medicationName}} </td>
        </ng-container>

       <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsOrderQueue"></tr>
       <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsOrderQueue;"
      ></tr>

        </table>

      </mat-card-content>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="submitSelectedRefills()">Submit Refill Orders</button>


      </mat-card>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatCardModule,MatSnackBarModule,MatProgressBarModule,MatInputModule,MatSelectModule,MatProgressSpinnerModule,MatToolbarModule,MatFormFieldModule,MatButtonModule, MatSidenavModule, MatIconModule, MatListModule, MatSortModule, MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu.component';
import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
import {RefillService} from './refill.service';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    FormsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    HttpModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTableModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/activerefills', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'activerefills', component:NavMenuComponent},

    ])
  ],
  providers: [RefillService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PharmacyRefills</title>
  <base href="">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe you guys are able to see something I don't see. Thank you!

Comment: No problems jump out at me. When you open up the developer console there's no errors? Also, if you inspect the html, can you find the script tags angular adds? Something like <script type="text/javascript" src="main.e5593a5f5120556468ff.js"></script>

Comment: This is what angular adds:

  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.91ec312f2354adbe42f9.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.1e8afa7f2c1e93144bd2.js"></script></body>
</html>

Comment: I have VS 2017 (version 15.8.2) I created new asp.net project using "Angular" template  and hit Run (F5). I get the same issue, browser is showing "Loading..." forever. I also made sure I have the latest Node.js. Still searching net for the solution.

Comment: ASPNET Docs say the template in VS uses old version of Angular (5 vs 6) https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/8163 . Could this be the culprit? Does anyone know how to update to latest Angular in ASP.NET project? Thank you!